# Erroneous Argument for uncorrelated implies Independence

Tags: distributions, self-study, normal-distribution, bivariate

I've been working on the problem where for a bivariate normal random variable (X,Y), uncorrelated implies Independence. However, I realized that I didn't use the bivariate normal assumption, so there is something wrong with my argument. Can someone point out the problem with the following:

Starting from the first direction. From $Corr(X,Y) = 0$, we can deduce that $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$.

This means that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} xy dF_{X,Y}(x,y) = \int x dF_X(x) \cdot \int y dF_y(y)$$
$$ = \int \int xy dF_X(x) dF_Y(y)$$

$$\implies \int \int xy f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy = \int \int xy f_X(x)f_Y(y)dx dy$$

thanks in advance

Comment: Your final line does not say "independent".  For that you would have to remove the integrals and have $xy f_{X,Y}(x,y) =  xy f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ for all $x,y$ (and then divide both sides by $xy$), but you have no reason to do so

Comment: Ah. Ok. That makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: you can safely work with the pdf here since we know it exists

For $(\Rightarrow)$, when replacing $\text{cor}(X,Y)=0$ in the expression of $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, do you see that the joint density factors into two products, one involving only $x$ and the other involving only $y$?

In general, this implication is false, i.e. there are random vectors which are uncorrelated but their density doesn't factor. The multivariate $t$ is one of these.

Comment: Got it. What should that line be instead? Or is the problem that I said E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]?

Comment: not sure I got your question...

Comment: I though that the densities factored into two products, since Corr = 0, implies that E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] = 0. So, I thought that the first line of my proof followed from applying the definitions to this. Why does that line not follow?

Comment: Yes $cor(X,Y)=0$ implies $E(XY)=E(X)(Y)$ whatever the distribution, but this has nothing to do with independence between $X,Y$ as you are asking in this post.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please consider accepting it.